# PSPAD how to search a specific word between similars in a huge text

Tags: python, full-text-search, notepad++, pspad

I have many words like the following list:

```
yellow
yellow_1
yellow_2
yellow_orange
yellow_blu
```

I would like only to find the words yellow (ex. like the first of the list) and to substitute with another one ex "blue".

I tried to use the classical ctrl+h but of course, trying to do this I have back all the list of the words that include the part yellow.

How can I solve this?

Best regards

Comment: PSPAD and Notepad++ are different editors; the title asks specifically about PSPAD. The question has nothing about Python. So why are the Python and Notepad++ tags added?

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<!\w)yellow(?!\w)`
- Replace with: `blue`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!\w)         # negative lookbehind, make sure we haven't a word character before
yellow          # word to be changed
(?!\w)          # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't a word character after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]